# How can I plot the 16,32 and 64 bin histogram of an image that is 8 bit on python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have an array of a gray scale image

```
  Array
```

sample of array like this;

```
    array([[[142, 142, 142],
    [143, 143, 143],
    [142, 142, 142],
    ...,
    [147, 147, 147],
    [148, 148, 148],
    [143, 143, 143]],

   [[142, 142, 142],
    [142, 142, 142],
    [142, 142, 142],
    ...,
    [148, 148, 148],
    [150, 150, 150],
    [147, 147, 147]],
```

And array type is

```
    Array.dtype
    dtype('uint8')
```

I want to plot  16, 32 and 64-bin-histograms of  this array, anyone have an idea?

Comment: the array values are represented using `uint8` but the values themselves are in the `0-255` range (since `uint8` can represent `2^8` values). Plotting a histogram of the values should be straightforward if that was your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you have an RGB image (3 channels). You likely would want to visualize its histogram by each channel (red, green and blue).

You can easily achieve this by using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). For example, given an RGB Image array `img` with the same data structure as your variable `Array`, you can plot the histogram for each channel by converting it to `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'red': img[...,0].ravel(), 
    'green': img[...,1].ravel(), 
    'blue': img[...,2].ravel()
})
```

And then plotting it using [`plot.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html)

```
df.plot.hist(bins=n_bins, alpha=.3, xlim=[0,255], color=['red', 'green', 'blue'])
```

Where `n_bins` is the number of bins.

---

For `n_bins=16`

[image]

For `n_bins=32`

[image]

For `n_bins=64`

[image]